# AttributeError: head not found when printing head() in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```py
import sklearn
```

Maybe I'm not understanding something fundamental here, and I just don't know what that may be.  How should I go about debugging this?

```
messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
print messages_tfidf
```

That part works fine, as intended.  But I run into trouble when I test my understanding of .head()

```
print messages_tfidf.head()
```

Outputs the error

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) 
>         1 messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
>         2 print messages_tfidf
>       ----> 3 print messages_tfidf.head()
>
> AttributeError: head not found

Can someone help me understand my logical gap here?

Comment: The `.head()` method is usually found in pandas `DataFrames` and `Series`; so it's very likely that `messages_tfidf` is neither a `DataFrame` nor a `Series`. You can double check by running `print type(messages_tfidf)`.

Comment: Does `sklearn` document the use of `head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head is a function of pandas DataFrame.

You can do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd

dframe = pd.DataFrame(messages_tfidf)
dframe.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

sklearn always works internally with numpy and returns numpy arrays. There is no head function for a numpy array.